Subir varios archivos PDF a AWS S3 con una misma referencia
Quería abrir un hilo para que alguien me pueda dar una idea de como subir varios documentos a S3 referenciados a una Orden.
Por ejemplo quiero adjuntar varios PDFs a una orden, digamos la '25789836'. De momento solo puedo adjuntar un documento, no se me ocurre como poder adjuntar varios.
Por ejemplo yo quiero adjuntar varios PDFs, words a una orden, pero a la hora de subirlo con AWS tengo que cambiar el método, pero no se que metodo es para que permita subir varios.
Obviamente en el frontend tengo que cambiarlo para que me deje seleccionar varios documentos, eso no es ningún problema, pero el método del backend sé que hay que cambiarlo y no se cómo.
Por favor, si alguien me pudiese ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo:
function normalizarNombreArchivo(nombreOriginal) {
  return nombreOriginal
    // Reemplaza espacios por guiones bajos u otro caracter
    .replace(/\s+/g, '_')
    // Elimina tildes y diacríticos
    .normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    // Opcional: Elimina caracteres que no sean alfanuméricos, guiones bajos o puntos
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9._]/g, '');
}

// Función para subir un archivo a S3 y devuelve la URL
const subirArchivoS3 = async (buffer, fileName) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'cubodefotos',
    Key: fileName,
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream', // Puedes especificar el tipo de contenido más adecuado
    ContentDisposition: 'attachment', // Esto fuerza la descarga del archivo
  }; // Aqui Cambiar la distribucion 

  try { // Primer caso del try 
    const { Location } = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    return Location; // Retorna la localización 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al subir el archivo a S3:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

// Función para actualizar la base de datos con la nueva URL para una OF
const actualizarUrlNubeTrabajosPorSubida = async (ordenfab, url) => {
  await pool.query('BEGIN');
  await pool.query(`UPDATE "TRABAJOS" SET urlnube = ARRAY[$1] WHERE ordenfab = $2`, [url, ordenfab]);
  await pool.query('COMMIT');
};

// Función para manejar la subida de archivos y la actualización de URLs
const subirArchivoYActualizarUrls = (req, res) => {
  upload.single('archivo')(req, res, async (error) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
    
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No se ha subido un archivo.' });
    }

    const extensionesPermitidas = ['.pdf', '.xls', '.xlsx', '.doc', '.docx', '.xlsm', '.csv'];
    const extensionArchivo = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase();
    if (!extensionesPermitidas.includes(extensionArchivo)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Tipo de archivo no permitido. Solo se aceptan .pdf, .xls, .xlsx, .doc, .docx, .xlsm, .csv' });
    }
    
    const ordenesFabricacion = req.body.ordenesFabricacion.split(',').map(of => of.trim());
    const promises = ordenesFabricacion.map(async ordenfab => {
      const nombreNormalizado = normalizarNombreArchivo(req.file.originalname);
      const newFileName = `documentos/${ordenfab}_${Date.now()}_${nombreNormalizado}`;
      const newFileLocation = await subirArchivoS3(req.file.buffer, newFileName);
      return actualizarUrlNubeTrabajosPorSubida(ordenfab, newFileLocation);
    });

    try {
      await Promise.all(promises);
      res.json({ message: 'Archivo(s) subido(s) y URL(s) actualizada(s) con éxito.' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al procesar la subida y actualización:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al procesar la subida y actualización de URLs.' });
    }
  });
};

Solo quiero saber como puedo asignar varios documentos a una referencia , por que no se me ocurre la verdad

No entiendo realmente a qué le llamas "referencia", quizás es porque estás dejando demasiado código y una explicación bastante extensa pero poco enfocada. Quizás porque el código no es un [mcve] y no se alcanza a apreciar dónde está claramente la dificultad, al menos para alguien que no es parte de tu equipo de desarrollo y no está en contexto. Esto se explica bien en [ask].

No logro entender para nada el problema.. subir uno o subir 10 deberia ser exactamente igual.. si recibiste diez archivos, despues los subis de a uno y listo.. cual seria el problema que tuviste particularmente?
